# Navigation drawer and Bottom Bar navigation in same app

Tags: android

I'm trying to use navigation drawer and bottom bar nav in my app.therefore i have created navigation activity first.then i tried to add bottom bar nav to that same activity,like below.

**inside `onCreate`**

```
BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
```

**Activity.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

without `BottomNavigationView` in Activity.xml,app is working.but when i add `BottomNavigationView` inside Activity.xml app crashed.nothing showing   in logcat.

how can i use both bottombar nav and navigation drawer in same activity?

Answer (score 0):

> Open this layout

```
 layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
```

> and then in that layout add your bottom navigation view widget

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Answer (score 0):

BottomNavigation and Navigation Drawer both uses OnNavigationItemSelectedListener to switch from one fragment to another.
Now, In your case you'll be having two menus
1-activity_home_drawer.xml

2-navigation.xml (Menu you created for BottomNavigation Bar)

So, you inside the method you'd have to write logic for both the menus.

```
  @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Navigation Drawer Menus below.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action

        selectedFragment = new Batteries();
        bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        selectedFragment = new Offers();
        bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }
    // Bottom Navigation Menus below
    else if (id == R.id.navigation_dashboard){
        selectedFragment = new Batteries();
    }else if (id == R.id.navigation_home){
        selectedFragment = new BatteryReport();
    }else if (id == R.id.navigation_notifications){
        selectedFragment = new ScanCode();
    }

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frameLayout, selectedFragment).commit();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```